# How could I create a terminal at the bottom

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

I could create a terminal with vim by running `:term` in the vim normal mode. However, this terminal is opened at the top of the window and I would like to open it in the bottom. How could I open it at the bottom?
 By the way, how could I change the height of this window?

Comment: Have a look at the great documentation: [`:help window-resize`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#window-resize) and read up on the `comand modifiers`, start reading at [`:help :vertical`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Avertical)

Comment: In neovim `:term` doesn't open terminals in split buffer; I don't know about vim. And you could look at `splitbelow` option.

Answer (score 23):

This question is a couple of years old now but I found it when I was looking for a way to open a terminal inside vim below a bunch of vertical splits. What I want looks something like this:

```
+----+----+----+
¦    ¦    ¦    ¦
¦ f1 ¦ f2 ¦ f3 ¦
+----+----+----+
¦   terminal   ¦
+--------------+
```

What you get with `:below terminal` or with `:set splitbelow` and then `:terminal` is:

```
+----+----+----+
¦ f1 ¦    ¦    ¦
¦    ¦    ¦    ¦
+----+ f2 ¦ f3 ¦
¦term¦    ¦    ¦
+----+----+----+
```

After a bunch of googling, I pieced this together. To get what I want above is actually pretty simple. Type `:botright terminal` or `:bo term`. (See [`:help :botright`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abotright) for more details.)

You can save a few keystrokes by putting this in your vimrc:

```
" open terminal below all splits
cabbrev bterm bo term
```

Then just type `:bterm` to open a terminal at the bottom.

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] and thanks for writing the answer! I did some small edits, please suggest a further edit if you disagree with any of the changes... Again, welcome!

Comment: Better might be `:command Bterm botright terminal`—the abbreviation also triggers when searching, where the command does not.

Answer (score 14):

In your ~/.vimrc add the line

```
set splitbelow
```

This will cause all splits to happen below (including terminal).

To change the height of the terminal (row x col)

```
set termwinsize=10x0 " 'termsize' didn't work - this did for me (GVIM 8.2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how could I change the height of the terminal, and I seem to observe that I could not copy contents in the vim-terminal as I did in pure terminal ?

Comment: Read `:help termwinsize` to answer the first question. It will tell you how to modify that. You can always look up things by `:help command` in this case `term` and scroll. For the second I don't actually know the answer but the help page would likely help.

Comment: I tried but failed before I asked. I simply add the following lines in my vimrc: ```set termwinsize = "10*0"``` and when I open vim and run command ```:ter```, the terminal still occupies half the screen. What mistake did I made then?

Comment: See also the `:below` command, e.g. `:below terminal`

Comment: @coincheung `10*0` means *at least* ten rows high. If you want 10 rows exactly, try `:set termwinsize=10x0`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a way to easily toggle a single terminal that would keep the same size and content.

My solution lies in two functions: the main one controls whether a terminal should be opened, the second opens a terminal split where we want on the screen.

If one or more terminal splits exist, they are hidden. Else, a terminal split is opened, either a new one or the first hidden terminal.

```
function! PutTermPanel(buf, side, size) abort
  " new term if no buffer
  if a:buf == 0
    term
  else
    execute "sp" bufname(a:buf)
  endif
  " default side if wrong argument
  if stridx("hjklHJKL", a:side) == -1
    execute "wincmd" "J"
  else
    execute "wincmd" a:side
  endif
  " horizontal split resize
  if stridx("jkJK", a:side) >= 0
    if ! a:size > 0
      resize 6
    else
      execute "resize" a:size
    endif
    return
  endif
  " vertical split resize
  if stridx("hlHL", a:side) >= 0
    if ! a:size > 0
      vertical resize 6
    else
      execute "vertical resize" a:size
    endif
  endif
endfunction

function! s:ToggleTerminal(side, size) abort
  let tpbl=[]
  let closed = 0
  let tpbl = tabpagebuflist()
  " hide visible terminals
  for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(bufname(v:val)) && index(tpbl, v:val)>=0')
    if getbufvar(buf, '&buftype') ==? 'terminal'
      silent execute bufwinnr(buf) . "hide"
      let closed += 1
    endif
  endfor
  if closed > 0
    return
  endif
  " open first hidden terminal
  for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val) && index(tpbl, v:val)<0')
    if getbufvar(buf, '&buftype') ==? 'terminal'
      call PutTermPanel(buf, a:side, a:size)
      return
    endif
  endfor
  " open new terminal
  call PutTermPanel(0, a:side, a:size)
endfunction

" Toggle terminal - bottom
nnoremap <silent> yot :call <SID>ToggleTerminal('J', 6)<CR>

" Toggle terminal - right
nnoremap <silent> yo<c-t> :call <SID>ToggleTerminal('L', 60)<CR>
```